# ArangoDB: Edges inserted in a collection are not shown in the graph

Tags: graph, arangodb, edges, visual-web-gui

I do my first steps with ArangoDB 3.11.2 on Ubuntu 22.04. I have a node collection, an edge collection and a graph which connects them (I installed the "knows" graph from examples to see want is neccessary).

The problem I encountered, is as following.

1. Edges which are inserted into the edge collection via the WebGUI are not shown in the graph (only nodes are visible).
2. Edges which are imported as a json file via arangoimport appear in the edges collection but are also not shown in the graph.
3. Edges, which are directly inserted in the graph appear and are also inserted in the edge collection.

Any ideas what might be the reason?

Regards